# np.random.randint causes ValueError: low >= high

Tags: python, numpy

I'm working on CapsNet from [here](https://github.com/XifengGuo/CapsNet-Keras)
, which is implemented on the MNIST dataset with 10 digits, but I've changed the code to work with a dataset with three classes. Model training and testing work fine, but the manipulate latent function causes an error:

```
  def manipulate_latent(model, data, args):
        x_test, y_test = data
        index = np.argmax(y_test, 1) == args.digit
        print(index)
        number = np.random.randint(low=0, high=sum(index) - 1)
        x, y = x_test[index][number], y_test[index][number]
        x, y = np.expand_dims(x, 0), np.expand_dims(y, 0)
        noise = np.zeros([1, 3, 16])
        x_recons = []
        for dim in range(16):
            for r in [-0.25, -0.2, -0.15, -0.1, -0.05, 0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25]:
                tmp = np.copy(noise)
                tmp[:,:,dim] = r
                x_recon = model.predict([x, y, tmp])
                x_recons.append(x_recon)
        x_recons = np.concatenate(x_recons)
        img = combine_images(x_recons, height=16)
        image = img*255
        Image.fromarray(image.astype(np.uint8)).save(args.save_dir + '/manipulate-%d.png' % args.digit)
```

The output is:

number = np.random.randint(low=0, high=sum(index) - 1)
ValueError: low >= high

Function call:

```
model, eval_model, manipulate_model = CapsNet(input_shape=x_train.shape[1:],
                                                  n_class=len(np.unique(np.argmax(y_train, 1))),
                                                  routings=args.routings)
manipulate_latent(manipulate_model, (x_test, y_test), args)
```

Comment: Please do not put arrows etc *inside* code snippets; the purpose of asking for the full error trace is that it specifies the exact location of the issue; if needed, you could add a relevant comment in the respective code line. Plus, this is obviously a list & `numpy` related question, and it has nothing to do with `machine-learning`, `neural-network`, or `deep-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're using `sum()` instead of `len()`.

```py
x = [False, False, False]
print(sum(x))
print(len(x))
```

Output

```
0
3
```

Notice, that `sum()` of an array of `False` is equal to **0**. While the `len()` is the size of the array.

Comment: that' raises another error                                                                                                  
x, y = x_test[index][number], y_test[index][number]
    
IndexError: index 123 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Comment: Now that's a totally different error, which is related to the vector and the model you're building. That is a separate question in itself.

Comment: Nitpick, but len(x) would be 3 in your example, not 2.